# Amana refrigerator controls change to coldest setting and freeze food

Tags: refrigerator

A couple weeks ago we noticed our Amana (Aff2534FEW3) refrigerator started freezing food. We found that the temperature settings for the refrigerator and for the freezer were at 7 which is the coldest setting.

Initially neither of the controls would let us change the setting to lower it. After cycling power to the unit I was able to turn down the setting on the freezer and I can sometimes turn it down on the refrigerator but it will either immediately go back up or will go back up after a few minutes. I push the down arrow a few times and the setting will say 4, for instance, a I can watch as it goes to 5->6->7.

I've even pushed the temperature down below 1 so it changed to - and turned the cooling off entirely. Then it just started climbing backup up again after a couple seconds until both controls showed 7.

We're currently planning to schedule a repair person to come out to fix it. It's out of warranty as far as I know. I thought I'd see if anyone here has any ideas.

Are there service manuals available anywhere? I work for an electronics company and we know our way around circuit boards so if I knew what to look for I suspect we could fix it. To me it seems like something is wrong with the circuit board for the controls.

Comment: If your frig is less than 10 yrs old you should be able to get the manual either directly at Amana's website or one of several "home user manual" repository sites.  However, it's almost always the case that the control PC board is unrepairable and will need replacement.

Comment: That's one of the frustrations for someone like me. The repair guy will likely say it can't be repaired but what he really means is that he doesn't have the knowledge to repair it. Given some info about the circuit board I would bet someone can repair it and my coworkers have the skill to do it, we'd just need to know how to extract it and maybe some info about the schematic.

Comment: Searching for repair manuals (as opposed to user manuals) lead me to repairclinic.com. They didn't have a repair manual but they do care parts for my refrigerator. The main circuitboard is $120 with a $60 core charge. Now I just need to figure out where that board is so I can decide if I want to attempt the repair myself in the hopes that it's the board that went bad.

Comment: Maybe,  but more often than not it isn't a simple case of a blown cap but rather a blown cap which fried some FPGA, so you end up having to get the new board anyway.

Comment: That's true @CarlWitthoft. I'm going to check the programming codes for the board because that's accessible from the normal control panel. If they are wrong then I'll set them correctly and see if it works. If they are right then I will likely order a new board.

Comment: i would try to make the coldest setting work for you. That means lying to it about the temp. A PTC thermistor can be paralleled with another plain resistor to offset the indicated temperature, while a NTC one can be series'd. or is that backwards? at any rate, intercepting the signal will be cheaper than replacing chips.

Comment: of course, you can bypass it in other ways as well. If you don't need the lights, and it gets too cold, you can use a thermal switch relay board (a few bucks on ebay) to cut power before it gets too cold. Not sure how long that would last, but i've seen it used to convert a chest freezer to a kegorator...

Comment: Oh, I like the way you think @dandavis. Brilliant ideas. I guess it depends on what the fridge does when it's at max cold. Maybe it just pulls out all the stops and ignores the temperature sensor. That's worth a try though. My current plan is to put the fridge into programming mode to make sure it didn't somehow get deprogrammed. Fortunately the proper program code is printed on the label in the fridge so I can easily verify it. I'm thinking maybe a power surge caused it to lose that code.